# How to use the css of the parent component to the child component in angular 5

Tags: angular

How to use the css of the parent component to the child component in angular 5

For example

```
<parent>
   <child></child>
</parent>
```

Need to use the css of the parent component to the child component.

Comment: ::ng-deep as a prefix to your CSS in the parent component allows you to style child component. It's not a great pattern though and might get deprecated in future.

Answer (score 0):

you can use combinator `::ng-deep` 
like this:

```
styles: [

     :host { color: black; }

     :host ::ng-deep parent {
       color:yellow;
     }
     :host ::ng-deep child{
       color:green;
     }
     :host ::ng-deep child.class1 {
       color:orange;
     }
     :host ::ng-deep child.class2{
       color:red;
     }

],
```

Comment: You don't actually need to prefix each style with :host

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the "ViewEncapsulation" property on your child component, set it to none. 
This will allow you to write css in parent that will be applied on child elements. 
Hope that will helps you.

Check the link bellow :
https://alligator.io/angular/viewencapsulation/